# Cross-Site Forgery on Auth Key in header?

Tags: javascript, rest, security, cookies, xss

I'm currently building a cloud API that will require an Authorization header in every request to the server. The header will contain an API key generated and stored on the server. I will not be checking cookies on the server, only the header.

On the client side, I plan to have the server return an API Key over HTTPS that can be stored locally. Every request from the client will auto-append the key as the header by taking the key out of a cookie or localstorage and placing it in a header.

Is this kind of header-only authorization vulnerable to a cross-site forgery hack? Any other possible security issues with an API key going in the header?